# How do I list WAF objects that do not have any resources using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'd like to list all objects in WAF that do not have resources connected to them using the aws cli in my terminal.

Is there anyway I can do this using the `aws wafv2 list-web-acl --name --scope <value>` AWS cli command with other perimeters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no cmd for that so I created a script to have the results placed in a file. Might come handy if needed by anyone on here

```
#!/bin/bash

#list the web acl objects with their corresponding arn and save it in a file
aws wafv2 list-web-acls --scope REGIONAL | grep "ARN" > output.txt

# Next generate only the ARN nos and save output in a seperate file
awk -F\" '{print $4}' output.txt > input.txt

#Create a file to store ARN numbers together with their resources attached
touch resources.txt

#loop through each line and  generate the resource attached to an ARN object based on its ARN no
while read p; do
  echo $p >> resources.txt && \
  aws wafv2 list-resources-for-web-acl --web-acl-arn $p >> resources.txt && \
  echo ------------------------ >> resources.txt
  #echo -e ' \t ' >> resources.txt
done < input.txt

#remove unwanted files
rm input.txt output.txt

#list webacl objects that do not have resources attached to them
grep -B 3 "\[\]" resources.txt | grep "webacl"

#remove any files left
rm resources.txt
```